# How to have python function input() within mysql command?

Tags: python

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="J"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE account SET balance = '100' WHERE address = 'input()'"

mycursor.execute(sql)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

I want to know how to put input within the SQL command? Any other ways than that? I know in php that you put it within , but in python? 
And what this code is all about is to refill or decrease customer balance.
like in db i got accounts and ofcourse there are alot of customers. How to make it so that it changes according to my input? thanks for reading.

Comment: Store the result in a variable. Use parameter binding as shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). Do not embed user input in a raw SQL string!

Answer (score 1):

Use the placeholder (`%s`) mechanism:

```
sql = "UPDATE account SET balance = '100' WHERE address = '%s'"
value = input()
mycursor.execute(sql, (value,)) # note well, the second argument must be a tuple, even if one-element only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="",
database="J"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
custumValue=input("Enter your Address")
sql = "UPDATE account SET balance = '100' WHERE address = %s"

mycursor.execute(sql,(custumValue,))

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```